# Adding dynamic variable to associative array in confideUser.php

Tags: php, laravel

In ConfideUser.php there is a variable `$rules`

`public static $rules = array(
        'username' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:users,
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:4|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'min:4',
    );`

I want to include the ConfideUser()->id dynamically like so

`public static $rules = array(
        'username' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:users,username,'.$this->id,`

or even

`public static $rules = array(
        'username' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:users,username,'.Auth::user(),`

But I don't know how to pass the model to the array. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hm, the current rules look like validation rules of which I can easily guess what they do, but what functionality would `,username,<id>` at the end provide there?

Comment: Your semantics is confusing judging from the code above. Just assume the code works, what is the meaning of comparing an authenticated user object with just a column username? Please provide more context of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to make sure that the username is not taken, but it's okay if they use their existing username. That is what `,username,<id>` is for. `Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID` http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#basic-usage